# How to make a get model request through another model?

Tags: python, django

I've been writing unit tests for a Django app and ran into. With this problem, many test classes are associated with, say, a single App class. How to take a single class model through this App.

```
app = App.objects.create(name='App1',
                         title='App Test Title',
                         app_type='F',
                         abstract='This is a test App',
                         description='**This is bold text test**',
                         active=True,
                         stars=4,
                         votes=45,
                         downloads=200,
                         has_releases=True)

class DevelopmentTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Development.objects.create(app=app,
                                   notes='**This is bold text test**')

    def test_development_created(self):
        development = Development.objects.get(app=app)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(development, Development))
        self.assertEqual(development.notes, 'Some test notes')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is wrong with this code? What does it mean to make a request "through" a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the `Development` model's code but I assume it has a `ForeignyKey` to `App`. This means that you *cannot* reliably use `Development.objects.get(app=app)` here since most probably one `app` will have many `development` (there will be many developments related to the same app). So the solution is simple: you have to keep a reference to the `Development` instance created in your `setUp`. FWIW, you should also create the `app` instance in the setUp method (and keep a reference to it) if you want your tests to work in proper isolation. IOW, your test should look something like:

```
class DevelopmentTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = App.objects.create(name='App1',
                         title='App Test Title',
                         app_type='F',
                         abstract='This is a test App',
                         description='**This is bold text test**',
                         active=True,
                         stars=4,
                         votes=45,
                         downloads=200,
                         has_releases=True)

        self.development = Development.objects.create(
            app=self.app,
            notes='**This is bold text test**')

    def test_development_created(self):
        development = self.development
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(development, Development))
        self.assertEqual(development.notes, 'Some test notes')
```

FWIW, you could (and possibly should) create the development instance directly in the test method here:

```
class DevelopmentTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = App.objects.create(name='App1',
                         title='App Test Title',
                         app_type='F',
                         abstract='This is a test App',
                         description='**This is bold text test**',
                         active=True,
                         stars=4,
                         votes=45,
                         downloads=200,
                         has_releases=True)


    def test_development_created(self):
        development = Development.objects.create(
            app=self.app,
            notes='**This is bold text test**')

        self.assertTrue(isinstance(development, Development))
        self.assertEqual(development.notes, 'Some test notes')
```

And finally testing that `Development.objects.create()` returns a `Development instance with the provided values is rather useless, you can safely consider that Django models "JustWork(tm)" (not that you'll never ever find a bug in django but really those are quite rare and will definitly NOT concern such fundamentals as creating a model instance).

Comment: Yes I used ForeignKeys in the model. Thanks for your help.